# Using a separate Google account for backend processes in MeteorJS

Tags: javascript, youtube-api, meteor

I'm creating an application for YouTube that utilizes some of the Analytics APIs for Content Owners.  The APIs require a user with sufficient permissions to be logged in, who can then retrieve reports for all the users of our application.

Currently our application can get YouTube User IDs, which is fine, but we need a separate account (other than the current user) to make requests to the API using the logged in user's ID.

How can I implement such a setup?  I know it would involve using offline authentication and periodically refreshing the access tokens, but I'm not quite sure how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've done a Google Analytics dashboard that refreshes the token in an interval. The admin chooses the GA Profile and it plots things. I needed to use a bunch of stuff to do that:

1. [Npm Integration](http://meteorhacks.com/complete-npm-integration-for-meteor.html) - So easy to use. Just take a look how to make methods calls sync.
2. [google-api-nodejs-client [alpha]](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/) - Integrate it with the Npm above. It refreshes the token for you automatically when you [Make Authenticated Requests](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/#making-authenticated-requests)

If you don't want to use google-apis-nodejs-client to refresh your token, you can use this code I've made to refresh the token by yourself:

```
var googleAccount = Accounts.loginServiceConfiguration.findOne({service: 'google'});
CLIENT_ID = googleAccount.clientId;
CLIENT_SECRET = googleAccount.secret;
REDIRECT_URL = '/_oauth/google?close';

var googleapis = Meteor.require('googleapis'),
    OAuth2Client = googleapis.OAuth2Client,
    client = getClient();

function getClient () {
    var client = Meteor.sync(function (done) {
        googleapis.discover('analytics', 'v3').execute(function (err, client) {
            done(err, client);
        });
    });
    if (client.err)
        throw new Meteor.Error(400, 'Client not received');
    return client.result;
}

function getOAuth2Client (user) {
    var accessToken = user.services.google.accessToken,
        refreshToken = user.services.google.refreshToken,
        oauth2Client = new OAuth2Client(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, REDIRECT_URL);

    if (user.services.google.expiresAt < +(new Date())) {
        var res = Meteor.http.call("POST", "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
            {params: {
                grant_type : 'refresh_token',
                refresh_token : refreshToken,
                client_id : CLIENT_ID,
                client_secret : CLIENT_SECRET
            }, headers: {
                "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
            }});
        accessToken = res.data.access_token;

        Meteor.users.update({_id: user._id}, {$set: {
            'services.google.accessToken': accessToken,
            'services.google.expiresAt': +(new Date()) + (1000 * res.data.expires_in)
        }});
    }

    oauth2Client.credentials = {
        access_token: accessToken,
        refresh_token: refreshToken
    };
    return oauth2Client;
}

Meteor.methods({
    'getAccounts': function () {
        var user = Meteor.users.findOne({_id: this.userId}),
            oauth2Client = getOAuth2Client(user),
            accounts = getAccounts(oauth2Client, client);

        return accounts;
    }
});
```

Comment: This provided a great base for my implementation of this. `google-api-nodejs-client` has come along a ways since then as well.